# ¿Qué motores de base de datos pueden hacer uso de PL/SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Muy buenas, tengo la siguiente pregunta...
¿Saben si puedo hacer uso de PL/SQL en cualquier sistema gestor de base de datos relacional como (mysql, posgrestSQL o SQL server)?
Por favor, si es tan amable, ayúdeme con su respuesta.

Comment: Deberías limitar tu pregunta al gestor sobre el que buscas esa funcionalidad

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, pero en realidad, quería hacer una pregunta abierta, para saber la opinión de varias personas :)

Comment: Oh ahora entiendo mejor, gracias por la preocupación, soy nuevo haciendo preguntas aquí. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL es exclusivamente el lenguaje de programación para la Base de datos de Oracle con el puedes crear Funciones , Paquetes, Procedimientos y Triggers.

T-SQL seria su homologo para bases de datos SQL Server ( microsoft ), cada motor de base de datos tiene su propio lenguaje y sus propias características.

Lo único que es standard entre los motores de base de datos es el lenguaje de consulta ANSI-SQL

---

**Edición** :
Algunos motores de base de datos como MariaDb se puede configurar pare ser compatibles.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle/

Comment: PL/SQLes compatible con MariaDB si se siguen ciertos pasos: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle/